# Phonegap blackberry 10 simulator - "Cannot post launcher object. Something went wrong here" - CLOSED

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, phonegap-build

I am working on a phonegap project and trying to deploy it on Blackberry 10 simulator. My simulator runs on VMware player.

As per the phonegap -Getting started guides, I am trying to deploy the project in my BB10 simulator from command line and getting the following errors -

```
package-app:
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\example\build\widget
 [copy] Copying 25 files to D:\example\build\widget
 [copy] Copying 3 files to C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10
WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11\Framework\ext
  [zip] Building zip: D:\example\build\cordovaExample.zip

build:
 [exec]
 [exec] D:\example>"C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWor
 ks SDK 1.0.4.11\third_party\node\windows\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\Research In
 Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11\lib\bbwp.js" D:\example\build\cordov
 aExample.zip -o D:\example\build --loglevel error
 [exec] [BUILD]   Populating application source
 [exec] [BUILD]   Parsing config.xml
 [exec] [BUILD]   Generating output files
 [exec] [BUILD]   BAR packaging complete

 load-simulator:
 [echo] This tool will not open the simulator for you
 [exec] Info: Sending request: Install and Launch
 [exec] Info: Action: Install and Launch
 [exec] Info: File size: 695220
 [exec] Info: Installing org.apache.cordova.example.testRel_ova_examplefce1a
  a22...
 [exec] Info: Processing 695220 bytes
 [exec] Info: Progress 64%...
 [exec] Info: Progress 100%...
 [exec] actual_dname::org.apache.cordova.example.testRel_ova_examplefce1aa22

 [exec] actual_id::testRel_ova_examplefce1aa22
 [exec] actual_version::1.0.0.0
 [exec] result::success
 [exec] Info: Launching org.apache.cordova.example.testRel_ova_examplefce1aa
  22...
 [exec] Error: Cannot post launcher object, something is wrong

 BUILD FAILED
 D:\example\build.xml:55: The following error occurred while executing this line:

 D:\example\qnx.xml:105: exec returned: 2

 Total time: 10 seconds
```

Now, all is well until it said `result:success` and the problem showed up there. It says "Cannot post launcher object. Something went wrong here".

I am new to BB environment and am confused with the "Something" went wrong here statement.
Can anyone look into this and throw some light on what the issue is? Why has this come-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with simulator initiation. After installing VMware player, once the BB simulator is used in it, wait for the environment to load. Check the signs of Blackberry logo appearing on screen and a progress bar appears around the logo.

Unless the simulator loads completely in VMware player, one cannot deploy an app into it.